# Extracting unique data frame and storing in separate files in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame df with stock data for a period of time. Now this data is mixed with all the symbols and date. I want to extract all unique symbols and store the data in separate csv.

```
SYMBOL SERIES      OPEN      HIGH       LOW     CLOSE  PREVCLOSE  TOTTRDQTY    TOTTRDVAL  TOTALTRADES       DATE
0   20MICRONS     EQ     92.30     94.50     88.55     91.95       91.5     303710  27898054.40         6418 2022-02-01
1  21STCENMGM     EQ     43.75     43.75     43.75     43.75       44.6       4162    182087.50           52 2022-02-01
2   3IINFOLTD     EQ     77.50     78.40     76.50     76.85       77.7     670585  51811319.20         6549 2022-02-01
3     3MINDIA     EQ  24989.90  25105.00  24712.25  25019.90    24989.9       3379  84467607.70         2324 2022-02-01
6      5PAISA     EQ    379.45    382.00    370.75    373.05      375.1      20498   7661615.15         1019 2022-02-01
```

Below is code and logic

- Step 1: I extracted the unique symbols and stored in a array symlist.
- Step 2: converted into a dataframe and renamed the column 'SYMBOL'
- Step 3: used a for loop to extract the SYMBOL u=in nbew dataframe df1

```
symlist=df['SYMBOL'].unique()
symlist=pd.DataFrame(symlist)
symlist.set_axis(['SYMBOL'], axis=1, inplace=True)
print (symlist.head(4))
       SYMBOL
0   20MICRONS
1  21STCENMGM
2   3IINFOLTD
3     3MINDIA

for i in symlist.index:
    df1=df[df['SYMBOL'].str.contains(symlist.index(i))]
    df1.to_csv('D:\\Trading\\datafiles\\test\\{}.csv'.format(symlist.index(i)))
```

But I'm getting an error

> File "C:\Users\Vaibhav\PycharmProjects\trading\candlepattern.py", line 33, in 
> df1=df[df['SYMBOL'].str.contains(symlist.index(i))]
> TypeError: 'RangeIndex' object is not callable

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use `groupby`:

```
for symbol, subdf in df.groupby('SYMBOL'):
    subdf.to_csv(f'D:/Trading/datafiles/test/{symbol}.csv', index=False)
```

Output:

```
>>> %cat 20MICRONS.csv
SYMBOL,SERIES,OPEN,HIGH,LOW,CLOSE,PREVCLOSE,TOTTRDQTY,TOTTRDVAL,TOTALTRADES,DATE
20MICRONS,EQ,92.3,94.5,88.55,91.95,91.5,303710,27898054.4,6418,2022-02-01

>>> %cat 3MINDIA.csv
SYMBOL,SERIES,OPEN,HIGH,LOW,CLOSE,PREVCLOSE,TOTTRDQTY,TOTTRDVAL,TOTALTRADES,DATE
3MINDIA,EQ,24989.9,25105.0,24712.25,25019.9,24989.9,3379,84467607.7,2324,2022-02-01
```

Comment: thanks this works. But i did not understand the logic of subdf in df.groupby('SYMBOL'):

Comment: Do you have multiple same symbols in your dataframe?